# What is an example of an Involutory matrix which is not Normal?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, involutions

In another question, a user kindly explained that not all Involutory matrices are Normal. I thought they were 'very Normal': both Unitary and Hermitian, but clearly they are neither always Unitary nor Hermitian.

Could you please give an example of an Involutory matrix which is not Normal?

Comment: Another example: 
$$
\pmatrix{1&t\\0&-1}
$$
for any $t \neq 0$.

Answer (score 1):

I just worked it out. Hope it helps somebody!

\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 2 \\
0.5 & 0
\end{pmatrix}